url_launcher ^6.3.1 UIApplication does not conform to protocol 'Launcher'
after updating this library to latest version when i try run this command:
flutter build ipa

i get this error:
Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): Type 'UIApplication' does not conform to protocol 'Launcher'
/Users/XXXX/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/url_launcher_ios-6.3.0/ios/url_launcher_ios/Sources/url_launcher_ios/Launcher.swift:21:0

Doctor output
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.24.1, on macOS 14.6.1 23G93 darwin-arm64, locale en-US)
    • Flutter version 3.24.1 on channel stable at /Users/mahdipishguy/Desktop/home/develop/flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision 5874a72aa4 (3 months ago), 2024-08-20 16:46:00 -0500
    • Engine revision c9b9d5780d
    • Dart version 3.5.1
    • DevTools version 2.37.2

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 34.0.0)
    • Android SDK at /Volumes/Mac/develop/sdk
    • Platform android-34, build-tools 34.0.0
    • ANDROID_HOME = /Volumes/Mac/develop/sdk
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jbr/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.7+0-17.0.7b1000.6-10550314)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 16.1)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Build 16B40
    • CocoaPods version 1.13.0

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 2023.1)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.7+0-17.0.7b1000.6-10550314)

[✓] Connected device (3 available)
    • macOS (desktop)                 • macos                 • darwin-arm64   • macOS 14.6.1 23G93 darwin-arm64
    • Mac Designed for iPad (desktop) • mac-designed-for-ipad • darwin         • macOS 14.6.1 23G93 darwin-arm64
    • Chrome (web)                    • chrome                • web-javascript • Google Chrome 130.0.6723.117

[✓] Network resources
    • All expected network resources are available.

• No issues found!



Just upgrade your package to latest one- url_launcher_ios: ^6.3.1

@ChiragSondagar how can i upgrade url_launcher_ios to latest version in flutter

Check your pubspec.yml file and if this framework is not there then you can overwride this.

try this

flutter clean
flutter pub upgrade
pod install


Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
